# Herança em banco de dados relacionais

Tags: banco-de-dados, orientação-a-objetos, modelagem, design-pattern, herança

um dos grandes desafios em desenvolver um software baseado em orientação a objetos é abstrair os dados de sua base para objetos afim de poder melhor manipula-los, hoje os frameworks ORM disponíveis facilitam bastante esta abstração,o problema mesmo é quando começamos a modelar o sistema a partir de objetos e principalmente quando damos hierarquia a eles utilizando heranças, como representar essas hierarquias no banco de dados relacional?

por exemplo

```
class veiculo
class carro extends veiculo
class moto extends veiculo
```

Qual a melhor maneira de representar estas hierarquias no banco de dados relacional, uma tabela para cada tipo? mesmo veiculo sendo uma classe abstrata?

Comment: Depende de que dados você tem em cada objeto (carro e moto). Considerando um conjunto mínimo de dados, uma única tabela serve (provavelmente uma única classe para representar ambos também).

Comment: Esta hierarquia teria que ser justificada pelo domínio, pelas regras de negócio que seu sistema atende. Se você vai registrar infrações de trânsito destes veículos, você não precisa de classes para diferenciá-los, você pode ter um atributo de tipo de veículo (carro, moto, ônibus...). Se o sistema vai atender uma loja de pneus, você sequer precisa de classe "veículo" ou "carro" ou "moto", pois o que interessa é o tipo de veículo que o pneu atende (atributo do "tipo de veículo" no pneu). Definindo bem a modelagem conceitual, a modelagem do banco relacional emerge.

Comment: @Caffé sim você esta certo, e eu sei que existem casos e casos, mas caso esta hierarquia seja justificada, minha pergunta é qual a melhor representação dessa hierarquia em um sistema de bando de dados relacional?

Comment: Neste caso, uma vez que a hierarquia seja desejada pelo domínio, eu referencio a primeira parte do meu primeiro comentário: `Depende de que dados você tem em cada objeto (carro e moto). Considerando um conjunto mínimo de dados, uma única tabela serve.`. Ou seja: assim como foram necessários mais detalhes para decidir pela hierarquia, estes mesmos detalhes são necessários agora para decidir o desenho do banco de dados.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Existem várias maneiras de mapear a relação de herança no banco. A melhor estratégia vai depender da situação (tipos de consultas que serão efetuadas contra a os dados, quantidade de campos comuns vs campos específicos, tamanho da hierarquia, quantidade de dados, etc).

### 1. Tabela por entidade

Cada tabela conterá não só os dados da classe filha como os dados da classe pai. Isso permite que consultas "independentes" entre carro e motos sejam mais simples e rápidas. Porém consultas buscando dados de mais de uma entidade requerem o uso de consultas com `union all` (o que é problemático por uma série de motivos).

### 2. Tabela única + coluna discriminadora

Uma única tabela conterá todos os dados de todas as entidades. Para diferenciar entre carros e motos usamos uma coluna discriminadora. Isso permite que consultas "genéricas" (i.e., sobre todos os veículos) sejam mais simples rápidas. É especialmente apropriada quando existem poucos atributos específicos de carro e moto (evitando assim uma grande quantidade de valores nulos).

### 3. Tabela principal + tabela filhas com FK para a tabela principal

Esse modelo é apropriado quando normalização for essencial e as tabelas filhas tiverem muitas colunas. Além disso essa estratégia é especialmente interessante para trabalhar com herança múltipla (uma entidade pode ser de vários tipos na hierarquia simultaneamente). A fraqueza dessa modelagem é que consultas requerem `join`, o que torna o código complexo e traz problemas de *performance* conforme a quantidade de dados e a profundidade da hierarquia vai crescendo.

### 4. Estratégias mistas

Nada impede que você modele parte da sua hierarquia conforme uma estratégia e parte conforme outra. Por exemplo, você pode ter uma tabela principal veículo com os dados comuns à todos os veículos (velocidade, tamanho, peso, etc), porém ter tabelas únicas para cada tipo de veículo (veículos terrestres, aquáticos, voadores, etc).

Todas as estratégias possuem suas vantagens e suas desvantagens; representações OO e relacionais são suficientemente diferentes para que existam vários problemas de mapeamento (ver [*Object-relational impedance mismatch*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch)). Se seu problema não puder ser adequadamente comportado por nenhuma das estratégias, existem também soluções com [Banco de dados orientados a objetos](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banco_de_dados_orientado_a_objetos), [NoSQL](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) (ver [Schemaless Data Structures](http://martinfowler.com/articles/schemaless/) do Martin Fowler), índices, etc. Cada um com suas respectivas forças e fraquezas.

Comment: ótima analogia das soluções, na terceira solução que no caso poderia envolver heranças múltiplas não ha maneira fora da programação de garantir que as classes filhas não tenha a mesma relação(FK) com a classe pai certo?

Comment: Tuyoshi Vinicius, tem sim. Dependendo do banco de dados você pode escrever, por exemplo, um `trigger before insert` , ou ainda escrever uma `stored procedure` para inserção dos dados conforme suas próprias regras e não dar acesso direto de escrita para as tabelas (ainda que nenhum dos dois métodos seja conveniente, caso seja necessário dá para fazer).

Comment: Veja que também é possível ter herança múltipla com as estratégias 1 e 2 (basta, por exemplo, você ter "flags" discriminadoras ao invés de uma coluna de valor único).