# Como representar na base de dados (android sqlite), uma classe que extende outra?

Tags: android, sqlite, sqlite3, sqlite-studio

Olá, 
Estou a trabalhar em android, tenho um caso em que uma tabela extende outra.

exemplo:

tabela Exercicio -> String dataInicio, String descrição .......etc

tabela Futebol -> String horaInicio, Int duracao....etc

Futebol extends Exercicio

e não sei como a representar na base de dados (sqlite) a tabela "Futebol", visto que tenho de ter associado à tabela "Futebol" a dataInicio da tabela "Exercicio".

Agradeço que me ajudem. 
Obrigado.

Comment: Acho que [essa questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35054/heran%C3%A7a-em-banco-de-dados-relacionais) possa te ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Estou entendendo que futebol é um tipo de exercício, então cria uma tabela "Futebol" e outra "Exercício", cada uma com suas chaves-primárias (id's). Na tabela Futebol você deve ter uma coluna (chave estrangeira ou FK) que vai receber a chave primária da tabela Execício. Por exemplo:

Exercício (id, descrição, ...)

Futebol (id, id_exercicio, duração, ...)

Talvez seja necessário habilitar constraints na inicialização do banco, para garantir que elas funcionem (não é padrão do SQLite elas já estarem ativas). Por exemplo, para fazer um DELETE CASCADE de um registro da tabela Exercicio (ao apagar um registro de Exercicio, apaga todos os registros de Futebol cujo id na chave estrangeira seja o mesmo do apagado em Exercicio) as constraints tem que estar habilitadas

Quando precisar resgatar dados correlacionados de ambas as tabelas faça um inner join (Futebol.id_exercicio = Exercicio.id) entre elas ou crie uma View com esse inner join já pronto para facilitar o uso de Content Providers (se for o seu caso).

Se precisar de mais detalhes, fala.