# CRUD Programação Orientada a Objectos

Tags: c#, sql, orientação-a-objetos, repository

Estou um pouco confuso em relação à forma como persistimos uma estrutura de programação orientada a objetos, nem sei bem como explicar, imaginemos o objeto **Pessoa** e por exemplo através de Herança crio o objecto **Professor** que herda a base da Pessoa.

Neste caso crio duas tabelas uma para pessoa e outra para professor?

Comment: Quase todo curso, livro e artigo sobre OOP dão exemplo errados de herança. Professor é um dos papeis que uma Pessoa pode ter, no caso um cargo temporário e só uma das múltiplas e possivelmente quase infinitas características que la pode ter. E por isso de forma geral discordo de tudo o que foi postado aqui e não dou uma resposta porque a pergunta está fechada. Mas sim, uma tabela para coisa, porque não é o mesmo objeto e sim dois objetos relacionados.

Answer (score 1):

O que eu estou entendendo que você está dizendo é sobre "Herança" ou é sobre "Composição" em OO.

É mais fácil você ler o artigo abaixo, mas basicamente é o seguinte:

Você tem um objeto "principal" chamado "Pessoa" que contém várias características (propriedades) como, por exemplo, "Nome", Endereço", "Telefone" ... bom isso todo mundo tem.
   Esse objeto "Pessoa" será herdado por um objeto chamado "Professor", pois o professor TEM todas essas propriedades acima. MAS o professor tem algumas outras propriedades que o "Pessoa" NÃO tem... exemplo: Matéria (que leciona)...

Mas, por favor, veja o link:

======================================

**OOP - Herança x Composição**

O paradigma da Orientação a objetos - OO - traz muitos conceitos novos e, para quem vem do paradigma procedural usando as linguagens estruturadas e do desenvolvimento orientado ao banco de dados, às vezes muitos desses conceitos podem não ser bem compreendidos.

```
namespace Herança
{
        public class Pessoa 
        { 
            private String nome;
            private String Endereco;
            private String Telefone;
        }

        public class PessoaProfessor : Pessoa 
        { 
            private String CPF; 
            private String Materia;
            public PessoaProfessor() 
            {} 
        }

        public class PessoaAluno : Pessoa
        {
            private String Notas;
            public PessoaAluno()
            {}
        }
}
```

## http://www.macoratti.net/11/05/oop_cph1.htm

Comment: Grato pela tua resposta.
Exatamente isso. A minha duvida é como faço a persistência disso na base de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Ola, a herança e mais usada como herança mesmo kkkk.

Tipo: professor, aluno, pais, etc.
Todos tem: nome, idade, sexo, endereço.

Neste caso você pode usar herança para evitar duplicão de codigo.
Na classe pessoa voce coloca todas essas propiedades, e nas classes filhas é herdado essas propriedades genericas.

No banco de dados é (relacional) costumo fazer o seguinte exemplo:

Na tabela pessoa tenho: id, nome, endereço, id_tipo_de_usuario.

Nessa tabela no campo id_tipo_de_usuario e inserido uma referencia de outra tabela, que contem os tipos de usuarios.

Na tabela tipo_de_usuario tenho os campos: id e tipo.
No campo tipo insiro: professor, aluno, responsavel ...

Assim quando consulto pessoa e retornado: id=0, nome=gabriel, endereço=rua c n 95, id_tipo_de_usuario = 0.

O id_tipo_de_usuario que é 0, é uma referencia da tabela tipo_de_usuario onde o id = 0;

Espero ter te ajudado a entender!

Comment: Grato pela tua resposta.
Pois, mas assim não consegues acrescentar propriedades consoante o tipo diferente pois não?

Comment: Ola, como assim consoante? dê um exemplo para entendermos.

Comment: Nesse caso que me apresentaste imagina uma pessoa com o tipo Aluno que herda as características da Pessoa.

Se quiseres dar uma propriedade nova ao aluno não consegues, correto?


Neste exemplo que me deste como transformas os dados depois em objectos?

Comment: consegue sim, na herança a classe filha herda tudo o que a classe pai possui e pode adicionar outros campos

Answer (score 0):

Gabriel, acredito que é isso que você procura:

Existem várias maneiras de mapear a relação de herança no banco. A melhor estratégia vai depender da situação (tipos de consultas que serão efetuadas contra a os dados, quantidade de campos comuns vs campos específicos, tamanho da hierarquia, quantidade de dados, etc).

**1. Tabela por entidade**

Cada tabela conterá não só os dados da classe filha como os dados da classe pai. Isso permite que consultas "independentes" entre carro e motos sejam mais simples e rápidas. Porém consultas buscando dados de mais de uma entidade requerem o uso de consultas com union all (o que é problemático por uma série de motivos).

**2. Tabela única + coluna discriminadora**

Uma única tabela conterá todos os dados de todas as entidades. Para diferenciar entre carros e motos usamos uma coluna discriminadora. Isso permite que consultas "genéricas" (i.e., sobre todos os veículos) sejam mais simples rápidas. É especialmente apropriada quando existem poucos atributos específicos de carro e moto (evitando assim uma grande quantidade de valores nulos).

**3. Tabela principal + tabela filhas com FK para a tabela principal**
Esse modelo é apropriado quando normalização for essencial e as tabelas filhas tiverem muitas colunas. Além disso essa estratégia é especialmente interessante para trabalhar com herança múltipla (uma entidade pode ser de vários tipos na hierarquia simultaneamente). A fraqueza dessa modelagem é que consultas requerem join, o que torna o código complexo e traz problemas de performance conforme a quantidade de dados e a profundidade da hierarquia vai crescendo.

**4. Estratégias mistas**

Nada impede que você modele parte da sua hierarquia conforme uma estratégia e parte conforme outra. Por exemplo, você pode ter uma tabela principal veículo com os dados comuns à todos os veículos (velocidade, tamanho, peso, etc), porém ter tabelas únicas para cada tipo de veículo (veículos terrestres, aquáticos, voadores, etc).

Todas as estratégias possuem suas vantagens e suas desvantagens; representações OO e relacionais são suficientemente diferentes para que existam vários problemas de mapeamento (ver [Object-relational impedance mismatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch) ). Se seu problema não puder ser adequadamente comportado por nenhuma das estratégias, existem também soluções com [Banco de dados orientados a objetos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banco_de_dados_orientado_a_objetos), (ver [Schemaless Data Structures do Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/articles/schemaless/)), índices, etc. Cada um com suas respectivas forças e fraquezas.

*** Veja mais em:

[Herança em banco de dados relacionais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35054/heran%C3%A7a-em-banco-de-dados-relacionais)

Comment: É mesmo isso Fabioln que eu queria.Muito obrigado.

Imaginemos que uso a abordagem da tabela com tipos TipoPessoa. Outra tabela onde guardo os dados gerais Pessoa.

(Tipo pessoa ex: Professor, Aluno, etc).

Do lado do meu código tenho as classes Aluno e Professor.

Não sei se me expliquei bem, mas o exemplo acima não se torna perigoso por eu conseguir editar a tabela TipoPessoa?

Usando um Layer Repository não fico com o sistema instável ao acreditar na fiabilidade da tabela Tipo?

Comment: #ferreira91, não entendo se torna perigoso pq a tabela "TipoPessoa" irá influenciar em todas as outras tabelas que são filhas dela. Isso tornará a manutenção muioto mai fácil! Imagine se você tiver uma tabela para cada pessoa... terá que alterar uma a uma!
Não acredito que o sistema fique "instável", mas que fique mais fácil de fazer manutenção. Desculpe... por favor, se gostou pode me pontuar?

Comment: #Fabioln já fiz o voto na tua resposta. Desculpa por não ter feito logo mas ainda sou novo por aqui.
O que quero dizer em ser Perigoso é que do lado do código podemos estar a trabalhar um tipo que na realidade pode não estar na base de dados.
No fundo tenho que limitar a edição da tabela dos Tipos

Comment: #ferreira91, desculpe, mas não concordo. A realidade do BD não precisa ser idêntica ao código, pois são situações distintas. Uma boa documentação atrelada ao sistema resolve esse impasse facilmente. Obrigado por votar.

Comment: #fabioln tens toda a razão. Muito obrigado por toda a tua ajuda ;)